# Error deploying Database - Database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version 10.2.0.0.0

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am transferring the Oracle database from one computer to another. The database was created in Oracle 11. I reinstalled the new controlfile to continue working with the database, but the following error occurred (see the pictures below). Before that I am enclosing a list of commands via CMD (executed as administrator)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN>set ORACLE_SID=LOVDTNAL
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Tue Oct 11 17:43:23 2022  
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

SQL> conn sys/sys as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> startup nomount pfile=D:\oracle\admin\LOVDTNAL\pfile\init.ora

SQL> CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "LOVDTNAL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
  2         MAXLOGFILES 16
  3         MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
  4         MAXDATAFILES 100
  5         MAXINSTANCES 8
  6         MAXLOGHISTORY 584
  7     LOGFILE
  8          GROUP 1 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO01.LOG'  SIZE 50M,
  9          GROUP 2 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO02.LOG'  SIZE 50M,
 10          GROUP 3 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO03.LOG'  SIZE 50M
 11    -- STANDBY LOGFILE
 12     DATAFILE
 13       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSTEM01.DBF',
 14       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\UNDOTBS01.DBF',
 15       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSAUX01.DBF',
 16       'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\USERS01.DBF',
 17       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\MAIN.DBF',
 18       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\INDEX.DBF',
 19       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\LOB.DBF',
 20       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\XDB.DBF'
 21     CHARACTER SET CL8MSWIN1251;
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "LOVDTNAL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
ORA-01130: database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version
10.2.0.0.0
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

P.S. This computer has several dozen databases that were created in Oracle 10.2.0 and Oracle 11.2.0. I did the same steps described above through Oracle 11.2.0. Unfortunately, in both cases, an error occurs:
[image]
Database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version 10.2.0.0.0

**PS
Running in Oracle 11.2.0 and error is not dissappear.**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>CD C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>set ORACLE_SID=LOVDTNAL

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Oct 11 17:39:41 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn sys/sys as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup nomount pfile=D:\oracle\admin\LOVDTNAL\pfile\init.ora
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2147483648 bytes
Fixed Size                  2078928 bytes
Variable Size             486541104 bytes
Database Buffers         1644167168 bytes
Redo Buffers               14696448 bytes
SQL> CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "LOVDTNAL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
  2         MAXLOGFILES 16
  3         MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
  4         MAXDATAFILES 100
  5         MAXINSTANCES 8
  6         MAXLOGHISTORY 584
  7     LOGFILE
  8          GROUP 1 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO01.LOG'  SIZE 50M,
  9          GROUP 2 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO02.LOG'  SIZE 50M,
 10          GROUP 3 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO03.LOG'  SIZE 50M
 11    -- STANDBY LOGFILE
 12     DATAFILE
 13       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSTEM01.DBF',
 14       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\UNDOTBS01.DBF',
 15       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSAUX01.DBF',
 16       'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\USERS01.DBF',
 17       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\MAIN.DBF',
 18       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\INDEX.DBF',
 19       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\LOB.DBF',
 20       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\XDB.DBF'
 21     CHARACTER SET CL8MSWIN1251;
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "LOVDTNAL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
ORA-01130: database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version
10.2.0.0.0
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

[image]

ORACLE HOME-
[image]

**UPDATE**
Now I noticed that when I exit `sqlplus`, `version 10.2.0` is shown to me, while I logged in via `product/11.2.0/.../BIN/sqlplus.exe`

[image]

the question is, how do I make it so that after `conn sys/sys` I log into `sqlplus` from `11.2.0`

Comment: the error message is clear, you can't do that. You need 11.2.0.4 on the machine, not 10.2

Comment: @thatjeffsmith sorry, but in this computer are 3-4 databases, which created in Oracle 11.2.0 and they work normally.This database was created on another computer,where was only Oracle 11.2.0.

Comment: then why are you running 10.2 sqlplus? switch over to 11.2 ORACLE_HOME and run sqlplus out of THAT home

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I edit my post and added cmd-log with Oracle 11.2.0

Comment: so now you're tying to open a 10.2 database with 11.2 software?

Comment: are you sure you set your ORACLE_HOME properly before starting sqlplus?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no, i trying open database in this path -> oracle\product\11.2.0\BIN , i think this path is means that i working with oracle 11.2.0 database. is right?

Comment: @gsalem I think,yes. Please check this command list in command window.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>CD C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>set ORACLE_SID=LOVDTNAL
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus /nolog

Comment: I don't see in the question nor in the comment what is the value of ORACLE_HOME. I see you're starting sqlplus from the 11.2 home, but that does not tell what's in the env variable ORACLE_HOME

Comment: @gsalem I added the variables of Oracle Home, with help regedit.See screenshot in main theme.

Comment: Please, in a cmd window,do:  echo %ORACLE_HOME% and show us the value it returns

Comment: @gsalem, already in main theme, simple answer - ORACLE_HOME

Comment: In the question, I see a print screen of regedit, that does not show the value of the different keys. And I'm asking to see what that variable has in your env when you execute sqlplus. If it is not set, set it to the directory containing the 11g distribution.

Comment: Just saw your newest edit, run the 'set' command to check again that no ORACLE_HOME is set, and if not do as I said in my previous comment. One last comment, I do not have access to a windows system running Oracle, and I don't remember last time when I used that env. I know oracle db well enough, but not windows.